# Default options for qemu-system-x86_64?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

Giving the following commands which works fine and the OS starts normally

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G  --enable-kvm example-of-os.qcow2
```

Is there a way, **a command or a file to consult**, to know what default options have been used for what has not been explicitly defined: harddrive, networking, usb, keyboard... ?

I am not talking about documentation, but result from the currently running VM.

Answer (score 1):

For example, firstly you would start with `-serial mon:stdio` on the command line, so as to have the built-in monitor available. Then you activate it with ^Ac (control-A c), which brings the `qemu` prompt.
There you use the `info` command.